# How to add link tag inside noscript tag its showing

Tags: html

I added  tag inside the  tag as following

```
<noscript>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${staticFilesUrl}/css/noscript-overrule.css" />
</noscript>
```

but in firefox when the javascript is enabled I see something like this

```
<noscript>
      &lt; link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/snsbank/css/noscript-overrule.css" /&gt;
</noscript>
```

event I tried to put style tag inside the noscript tag still in firefox I got the following result

```
<noscript>
    &lt; style &gt; #whiteBox{ width:30%; &lt/style&gt;
</noscript>
```

can anyone tell me how can I avoid this?

Comment: Please give some more explicit code

Comment: to format code, indent it with 4 spaces, or select it and press `010101` button in message toolbar or `Ctrl+K` key. Also see the right column for formatting rules, while editing the message. As to the actual problem: apparently you're using a view technology which is escaping HTML for some reason (if you're really getting `&lt;` instead of `<` and so on). Please mention which view technology you're using. This is then not a HTML specific problem.

Comment: please don't malform the formatting once again. I've rollbacked it for you. Please edit carefully. Pay carefully attention to the preview area below the message editor.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297643/opposite-of-noscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask in a comment: "if I want to use one css file only if javascript is disabled then what should I do?"

Two ways at least (probably more):

1. Have a default stylesheet that is for without javascript that always loads. Then, if javascript is enabled, use a `<script>` tag in the `head` to load a different stylesheet after the default to override the styles.
2. If you just have a few things that change, have one style sheet and have a class on your `body` of `NoJavascriptEnabled` that you use to target those few styles when javascript is not enabled, and then use javascript to *remove* that class if javascript is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

@Vipul - your solution should work in modern browsers.  Your question indicates that with javascript enabled you see the escaped html in the markup - is that also rendering like that in your browser?  (it shouldn't if javascript is enabled.)  If that isn't the case, the invalid markup you see when JS is enabled shouldn't be a problem because who cares what it looks like if the garbage isn't visible.

@Sarfraz - the  tag is used for html (not javascript), to display markup when javascript is not available - disabled or unsupported.  Adding link tags there is a common approach to load a specific stylesheet when javascript is not available.  Despite it being a non-standard approach as @Geert points out - it does work.

In this case it seems @Vipul was seeing some weird markup in firebug - FF6 supports it though.

In either case you should still take heed of the second point of advice in @Scott's answer - don't use the first as that adds extra (albiet a probably small) load to your server for 99% of internet users who have js enabled.  Stick to defaulting a "no-js" class to your html tag and remove it with javascript in the head. Be sure to do that in your head otherwise you'll [fouc the browser.](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/)

The exception to @Scott's rule is if you need to load a massive amount of CSS for user's without JS enabled.  In that situation I would recommend only linking to the css if JS is disabled via the noscript tag.  Why punish 99% of users who embrace a dynamic web environment because you need to kludge in style fixes for the remainder of the web?

Answer (score 0):

`<link>` is only allowed in the head section of an HTML document, not in the body. Are you placing this code in the head of the document?

Answer (score -1):

CSS is not a script, the `<noscript>` tag is used for javascript in case it is disabled. Why are you doing that? It is not used for CSS like you are doing.

Comment: if I want to use one css file only if javascript is disabled then what should I do?

Comment: @Vipul: See this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled