# Css fallback when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, fallback

With jQuery Mobile, I use this snippet to call libaries...

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined') 
{
    document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
    document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'));     
    document.write(unescape('%3Clink rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
    document.write(unescape('%3Clink rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
}
else
{
    document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
    document.write(unescape('%3Clink rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
    document.write(unescape('%3Clink rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
}
</script>
```

But if JavaScript is disabled, how to call stylesheets?

If I use (I'm a bit stupid!)...

```
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
</noscript>
```

... My page is blank.

Thanks for your help.

Vincent

Comment: Check your strings and remove trailing `%3E%3C/script%3E` where it is not needed. But first of all stop using `document.write`.

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300451/how-to-add-link-tag-inside-noscript-tag-its-showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) approach is to use JavaScript to add a class called "js" to the HTML tag on load, and remove a class called "no-js" which (in this case) you add yourself.

Now, you can add some CSS styles only to descendants of `.js` and others only to descendants of `.no-js`, customizing either one to your liking.