# Javascript enable prompt

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [opposite of <noscript>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297643/opposite-of-noscript)

I have a static html page as following:

```
<head>
<noscript>Please Enable JavaScript</noscript>
</head>

<body>
<br />
HELLO
</body>
```

This will prompt the user to enable Javascript. But "HELLO" is getting displayed no matter whether JavaScript is disabled or enabled. I want "HELLO" to get displayed if JavaScript is enabled and want the prompt to appear and "HELLO" to hide when JavaScript is disabled. It will be better if it is a cross-browser solution. How can I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297643/opposite-of-noscript. By the way, you shouldn't display text inside `<head>` tag. Move the `<noscript>` tag inside the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `Hello` a javascript, like this...

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("HELLO");
</script>
<noscript>Please Enable JavaScript</noscript>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently has `HELLO` displaying in plain HTML, regardless if JavaScript is enabled or not. And the `<noscript>` tag belongs within the `<body>`.

The example below will write `HELLO` if the user has JavaScript enabled. But if JavaScript is disabled, `Please Enable JavaScript` will be shown instead.

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("HELLO");
    </script>
    <noscript>
        Please Enable JavaScript
    </noscript>
</body>
```